# Passing const reference leads to paradox in code..?

Tags: c++, vector, reference, constants

Ok so I have a function within a class named vector_ref

```
class vector_ref {
    public:
       int* data() const { return m_data }
       void retarget(std::vector<int> const& _t) 
       { m_data = _t.data(); 
         m_count = _t.size() }
    private:
       int* m_data;
       size_t m_count;
}
```

I am trying to retarget a vector_ref object to an existing vector object named v which is populated by ints and call data().

```
vector_ref<int> tmp;
tmp.retarget(const_cast<std::vector<int> const&>(v));
tmp.data(); // error here
```

The pass to retarget compiles, but calling data() yields the error:

```
invalid conversion from const int* to int* { m_data = v.data() ... }
```

This makes sense to me, as the member variable `m_data` isn't `const`, but given this class definition how can I ever `retarget` to an existing `vector`.  If I have to pass by `const` reference to `retarget()`, which sets the non-`const` member variable `m_data`, how can I ever hope to successfully compile code that successfully retargets the `vector_ref` instance ?

Comment: What is your intent? By taking a parameter as `const&`, you declare that you will not change it, but then you want to take a mutable pointer to it, indicating that you can change it through that pointer.

Comment: I'm reading code from somebody else's project, trying to figure out why they wrote it this way.

Answer (score 3):

Just declare `m_data` as

```
const int* m_data;
```

This doesn't mean that `m_data` is `const`. It means that the you cannot modify the `int` which `m_data` points to. So you can still do this:

```
m_data = _t.data();
```

But you can't do this:

```
*m_data = x;
m_data[5] = y; // or this
```

By the way, there's no need for your `const_cast`. You would need `const_cast` if you were removing the const qualifier (i.e. passing a `const` object to a function that expects a non-const reference). You don't need it in order to pass a non-const object to a function which accepts a const reference.